# Resolve deprecation warning "DeprecationWarning: Compilation.cache was removed in favor of Compilation.getCache()"

Tags: node.js, webpack, deprecation-warning, webpack-loader

I use the npm package [service-worker-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/service-worker-loader). I get this waring when building the project:

> node:25260) [DEP_WEBPACK_COMPILATION_CACHE] DeprecationWarning: Compilation.cache was removed in favor of Compilation.getCache()

I have discovered through using:

```
node --trace-deprecation node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --mode=development
```

That the problem is in the following code:

```js
onCompilerHook(compiler, 'compilation', compilation => {
  if (compilation.cache) {
    if (!compilation.cache[subCache]) {
      compilation.cache[subCache] = {};
    }

    compilation.cache = compilation.cache[subCache];
  }
});
```

I am using the latest version (4.0.2) of the package.
Was that deprecation fixed? Is there any possible fix?

Comment: Do you need this package at all if [webpack 5 release notes](https://webpack.js.org/blog/2020-10-10-webpack-5-release/#native-worker-support) introduce native worker support?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/